# Creating a private group room in the chat application

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, chat, python-sockets

I am writing a chat application. Everyone who connects to the client chats with each other by writing the messages they want. But I want to add the feature of creating private groups.

[client chatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6KCP.png)
After creating the private room, the room I am in should be written next to my name.
After joining the room, people who do not join the room should not exchange messages.
but after joining the room the program crashes.
Even if I leave the room, I cannot send messages etc.

```py
import os
import socket
import logging
import hashlib
import argparse
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import init, Fore, Style

clients = {}
clients_lock = threading.Lock()

# Groups dictionary to keep track of groups
groups = {}
groups_lock = threading.Lock()

class Group:
    def __init__(self, name, password=None):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password  # Store the hashed password
        self.members = set()

    def add_member(self, client_handler):
        with groups_lock:
            self.members.add(client_handler)

    def remove_member(self, client_handler):
        with groups_lock:
            self.members.remove(client_handler)

    def send_to_all(self, message, from_member):
        with groups_lock:
            for member in self.members:
                if member != from_member:
                    member.client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

def log_setup(loglevel, logfile):
    numeric_level = getattr(logging, loglevel.upper(), None)
    if not isinstance(numeric_level, int):
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid log level: {loglevel}")

    logging.basicConfig(level=numeric_level,
                        format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s",
                        handlers=[logging.FileHandler(logfile),
                                  logging.StreamHandler()])

class ClientHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, client_socket):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        self.username = None
        self.group = None

    def run(self):
        global clients
        logging.info(f"New client connected: {self.client_socket.getpeername()}")  # Eklenen log


        # Ask for and validate the username
        while True:
            try:
                self.client_socket.send("Enter your username: ".encode('utf-8'))
                username = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').strip()
                with clients_lock:
                    if username in clients or not username:
                        self.client_socket.send(
                            "This username is already taken or invalid. Please enter a different name.".encode('utf-8'))
                        continue  # After sending the error message, return to the beginning of the loop
                    else:
                        self.username = username
                        clients[self.username] = self.client_socket
                        self.client_socket.send("Username set successfully.".encode('utf-8'))
                        break

            except BrokenPipeError as e:
                if e.errno == 32:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"An unknown error occurred: {e}")
                return
        # Process messages
        try:
            while True:
                message = self.client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == "/userlist":
                    with clients_lock:
                        userlist = "\n".join([f"\t{i + 1}) {user}" for i, user in enumerate(clients.keys())])
                        response = f"Connected Users:\n{userlist}"
                        self.client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
                        continue
                if message == "/help":
                    response = Fore.BLUE + "Help Menu:\n" \
                                           "\t/help                                -> Help Menu\n" \
                                           "\t/exit                                -> Exit the program.\n" \
                                           "\t/userlist                            -> View the list of connected users.\n" \
                                           "\t/dm [user] [message]                 -> Send a direct message to a user.\n" \
                                           "\t/changeuser [new_username]           -> Change your username.\n" \
                                           "\t/creategroup [group_name] [password] -> Create a new group with an optional password.\n" \
                                           "\t/joingroup [group_name] [password]   -> Join an existing group with the correct password.\n" \
                                           "\t/leavegroup                          -> Leave the current group.\n" \
                                           "\t/listgroups                          -> List all available groups.\n" + Style.RESET_ALL
                    self.client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
                    continue
                if message.startswith("/changeuser "):
                    _, new_username = message.split()
                    with clients_lock:
                        if new_username in clients:
                            self.client_socket.send(
                                "This username is already taken. Please choose another one.".encode('utf-8'))
                        else:
                            # Remove the old username and add the new one
                            del clients[self.username]
                            self.username = new_username
                            clients[self.username] = self.client_socket
                            self.client_socket.send(f"Username changed to {new_username}.".encode('utf-8'))
                    continue

                if message.startswith("/dm "):
                    _, recipient, *dm_msg_parts = message.split()
                    dm_message = " ".join(dm_msg_parts)
                    with clients_lock:
                        if recipient in clients:
                            clients[recipient].send(f"[DM from {self.username}] {dm_message}".encode('utf-8'))
                            self.client_socket.send(f"[DM to {recipient}] {dm_message}".encode('utf-8'))
                        else:
                            self.client_socket.send("Specified user not found.".encode('utf-8'))
                    continue

                """ this part is the group start start"""

                if message.startswith("/creategroup "):
                    _, group_name, *password_parts = message.split()
                    password = " ".join(password_parts)
                    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() if password else None
                    group = Group(group_name, hashed_password)
                    with groups_lock:
                        groups[group_name] = group
                    group.add_member(self)
                    self.group = group
                    self.client_socket.send(f"Group '{group_name}' created.".encode('utf-8'))
                    continue

                if message.startswith("/joingroup "):
                    _, group_name, *password_parts = message.split()
                    password = " ".join(password_parts)
                    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() if password else None

                    with groups_lock:
                        group = groups.get(group_name)
                        if group:
                            print(f"Group found: {group_name}")  # Debug print
                            if group.password is None or group.password == hashed_password:
                                group.add_member(self)
                                self.group = group
                                print(f"Sending join confirmation to {self.client_socket}")  # Debug print
                                self.client_socket.send(f"Joined group '{group_name}'.".encode('utf-8'))
                            else:
                                print(f"Password mismatch for group: {group_name}")  # Debug print
                                self.client_socket.send("Failed to join group: Wrong password.".encode('utf-8'))
                        else:
                            print(f"Group not found: {group_name}")  # Debug print
                            self.client_socket.send("Failed to join group: Group does not exist.".encode('utf-8'))
                    continue

                if message == "/leavegroup":
                    if self.group:
                        self.group.remove_member(self)
                        self.client_socket.send(f"Left group '{self.group.name}'.".encode('utf-8'))
                        self.group = None
                    else:
                        self.client_socket.send("You are not in a group.".encode('utf-8'))
                    continue

                if message == "/listgroups":
                    with groups_lock:
                        group_list = ["name".ljust(20) + "password"]
                        for i, (group_name, group) in enumerate(groups.items(), 1):
                            indicator = '*' if group.password else ''
                            group_list.append(f"{i}) {group_name.ljust(20)}{indicator}")
                        response = "Available Groups:\n\t" + "\n\t".join(group_list)
                        self.client_socket.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
                    continue
                """ and this part is the group stop"""

                if not message or message == "/exit":
                    break
                current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                broadcast_message = f"[{current_time}] {self.username}: {message}"
                with clients_lock:
                    for usr, client in clients.items():
                        if usr != self.username:
                            client.send(broadcast_message.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass

        # Cleanup when the client exits
        with clients_lock:
            del clients[self.username]
        self.client_socket.close()

def start_server(host, port):
    try:
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.bind((host, port))
        host_ip, host_port = server_socket.getsockname()
        server_socket.listen(5)
        print("Server started. Waiting for clients...")
        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}Host information: {Style.RESET_ALL}{host_ip}:{host_port}")
        logging.info(f"Server started on {host_ip}:{host_port}")  # Eklenen log

        while True:
            current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            print(f"[{current_time}] {client_address} Connected.")
            logging.info(f"Accepted connection from {client_address}")  # Eklenen log
            handler = ClientHandler(client_socket)
            handler.start()

    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 98:
            print("Address already in use, you wild thing :D")
            logging.error("Address already in use")  # Eklenen log
        else:
            print(f"An error occurred while starting the server: {e}")
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")  # Eklenen log
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program terminated.....")
        logging.info("Server was terminated by keyboard interrupt")  # Eklenen log


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Start the chat server.")
    parser.add_argument("--host", default="0.0.0.0", help="The IP address to bind the server to. (Default: 0.0.0.0)")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=12345, help="The port number to bind the server to. (Default: 12345)")
    parser.add_argument("--loglevel", default="INFO", choices=["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRITICAL"],help="Set the logging level (Default: INFO)")
    parser.add_argument("--logfile", default="server.log", help="Set the log file name. (Default: server.log")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    log_setup(args.loglevel, args.logfile)  # Log ayarlarını başlatma

    start_server(args.host, args.port)
```

and client.py

```py
import socket
import argparse
import threading
from colorama import init, Fore, Style

init(autoreset=True)

def start_client(host, port):
    try:
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect((host, port))
        message_lock = threading.Lock()
    except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
        if e.errno == 111:
            print("Connection refused")
        else:
            print(f"An unknown error occurred {e}")
        return

    # Firstly, get the username
    while True:
        username_prompt = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(Fore.CYAN + username_prompt, end="")
        username = input()
        client_socket.send(username.encode('utf-8'))
        response = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if "Please enter a different name." not in response:
            break
        print(Fore.RED + response)
    print(Fore.BLUE + "Help Menu:")
    print("\t/help       -> Help menu")

    # Listen for messages from the server
    def listen_to_server():
        nonlocal username  # Make sure we can modify the outer scope's username variable
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            with message_lock:
                # Check for username change confirmation and update if found
                if "Username changed to " in data:
                    username = data.split("Username changed to ")[1].rstrip(".")  # Extract the new username
                    print(f"{Fore.GREEN}\n{data}\n{Style.RESET_ALL}{username}:{Fore.YELLOW} Enter your message: {Style.RESET_ALL}",end='')
                else:
                    print(f"{Fore.GREEN}\n{data}\n{Style.RESET_ALL}{username}:{Fore.YELLOW} Enter your message: {Style.RESET_ALL}",end='')

    threading.Thread(target=listen_to_server, daemon=True).start()

    while True:
        try:
            print(f"{username}: {Fore.YELLOW}Enter your message: {Style.RESET_ALL}", end='')
            message = input()
            if message == "/exit":
                client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
                break
            client_socket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            if e.errno == 111:
                print("Connection refused")
            else:
                print(f"An unknown error occurred {e}")

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(Fore.RED + "\nClosing connection...")
            client_socket.send("/exit".encode('utf-8'))
            break

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Connect to the chat server.")
    parser.add_argument("--host", default="127.0.0.1", help="The server's IP address.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=12345, help="The port number of the server.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start_client(args.host, args.port)
```

Comment: What is the error message when the application is crashed?

Comment: The design is fundamentally flawed because it assumes TCP is message-based. It is not.  Don't assume one send equals one recv